# Use intptr_t to do some arithmetic computing

Tags: c++

I want to keep the memory address is 16 byte alignment when memory alloc (In arm64)

When I malloc a space I get a address:

```
char * addr = (char*)malloc(1024);
```

Then addr may not Multiple of 16！ So I want to do some arithmetic computing:

```
uintptr_t ip = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(addr);
ip = (ip / 16) * 16; // here ip is Multiple of 16.
```

So how can I cast ip to a memeory address? use (char*) or (void*)

```
char * newIP = reinterpret_cast<char*> (ip) // is this right?
```

Is thess is bug free methond? What about portable?

Comment: First of all don't use `malloc` in C++, not even for just allocating a a chunk of bytes. It's a bad habit, and you should use `new[]` instead (I would normally recommend `std::vector` instead, but your alignment requirement puts a stop to that). Secondly, don't forget to add at least 15 bytes to the amount you allocate, since your arithmetic will discard part of the memory. Lastly, keep the original pointer you received, as you need it when freeing the memory.

Comment: I think you might be [looking for `std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align), but I'm not sure enough to turn that into an answer. And since it would basically be a link to the same documentation page as this comment, I'm not sure it would be a good answer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  hi   Some programmer dude. thank for your proposal, it is indeed important. But the code fragment just a example to simplify my question. I wonder if there is a problem with this cast.

Comment: Hi user4581301 @user4581301 thank for your suggestion, I will try std::align also

Answer (score 0):

The address is returned by memory allocation, so you cannot align it to lower address direction. You can discard a little bytes at beginning when the address is not aligned;
like this:

```
size_t unit_ = 16;
size_t cbSize_desired = 1024;
void* addr = malloc(cbSize_desired + unit_ - 1);
uintptr_t ip = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(addr);
char* newIP = reinterpret_cast<char*>((ip + unit_ - 1) / unit_ * unit_);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void *addr = malloc(1024+15);
void *newIP = ((uintptr_t)addr+15) & ~ (uintptr_t)0x0F;
```

When you fee the memory again, make sure you free the original addr pointer!